# Selenium find_element_by_link_text not working for full urls

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working on a Python/Selenium program that makes a file of urls I've visited, then highlights them in the browser when I do a Google Search so I don't waste time visiting these sites again.

```
#searched Google for: "county fair" site:etypeservices.com
element = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("etypeservices.com")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'", element)
```

So far, so good. But if I try to select the full webpage using the same method...

```
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("http://archives.etypeservices.com/Wauneta1/Magazine132532/Publication/Magazine132532.pdf")
```

I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: That's seems like the href. The link text is the text between <a> and </a>

Comment: please share the html of the element.

Comment: <a href="http://archives.etypeservices.com/Wauneta1/Magazine132532/Publication/Magazine132532.pdf" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=http://archives.etypeservices.com/Wauneta1/Magazine132532/Publication/Magazine132532.pdf&amp;ved=2ahUKEwi_o5ysr9TkAhVJHjQIHbVcDc8QFjAAegQIABAC"><h3 class="LC20lb"><div class="ellip">Wauneta, NE</div></h3><br><div class="TbwUpd"><cite class="iUh30 bc">archives.etypeservices.com › Wauneta1 › Publication › Magazine132532</cite></div></a>

Comment: "partial_link_text" refers to the text from a rendered hyperlink, not the url it links

Answer (score 0):

As per `find_element_by_partial_link_text` function documentation:

> Finds an element by a partial match of its link text.
>
> **Args**:
>
> link_text: The text of the element to partially match on.

Given you have the following link definition:

```
<a href="http://example.com">Example Domain</a>
```

You can match it like:

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Example")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Domain")
```

If you want to locate the element by its partial URL you need to use [`href` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp), it can be done using [XPath Selector](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-xpath-selector) and [XPath contains()](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) function like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://example.com')]")
```